# Flutter Local/Push Notifiactions

Tags: flutter, dart

I need an adivce how to listen for push notification in flutter without using FCM (Firebase).

I was thinking about streams.

My idea is to on backen (.NET) create stream which pushes notification to flutter app.
It will work? or regular REST api and GET request? how to handle this task?

i am planning to use this lib

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-readme-tab-

Comment: You can do all that with `Firebase cloud functions`. In your case, the backend can send request to the FCM api.

I would suggest you combine FCM and `flutter local notifications` to achieve better functionality.

Comment: hello as i said i can't use FCM